# Is my USB 2.0 device running at full speed?

Tags: hardware, usb

How can I tell if my USB flash drive is running at full USB 2.0 speed? Currently I'd just like to verify that the drive is plugged into a 480 Mbps port, but in the past I've been unsure if a given device was USB 2.0 or an older revision. I'd like a way to identify its capabilities other than testing read/write speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could check out

```
lsusb -v
```

On my system I get for example this line (and much more information):

> Port 6: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect

Alternatively you can issue a:

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

in one terminal and then plug in the USB flash drive. On my system I get for example this message:

> Sep 15 22:10:40 foo kernel: [405279.750140] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 24

ehci_hcd is the USB 2.0 controler module in the kernel (i.e. everything is ok, the USB 2.0 stick is used with the right speed).

Unless you get a follow up message like this:

> Sep 15 22:15:25 foo kernel: [405564.451402] usb 6-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub

(in this case probably compatibility problem with a low quality USB 2.0 stick (Kensington), since the computer's USB port supports USB 2.0 high speed devices otherwise)

With a non USB 2.0 high speed stick I get this message:

> Sep 15 22:15:25 foo kernel: [405564.300127] usb 6-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4

If your user account does not have access to /var/log/kern.log (or another system dependent kernel log message file location), you could use the command *dmesg* as an alternative to display the contents of the kernel message buffer. The disadvantage of dmesg is just that it does print such nice time stamps and it does not have a *follow output* option.

Comment: where `/var/log/kern.log` might be a different file. `dmesg` should have the same info.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Good point, this morning I thought that I should had mention dmesg as well. ;)

Answer (score 16):

```
lsusb -t
```

shows the speed directly after the device name.

Answer (score 12):

Using `lsusb -t` you can see the specifications of the USB:

```
$ sudo lsusb -t

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

But to check the speed of the USB, and see if it is working right you need to do a speed test with `hdparm`

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdd

/dev/sdd:
Timing cached reads:   7642 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3822.03MB/sec  
Timing buffered disk reads:  96 MB in  3.05 seconds =  31.44MB/sec
```

The example is one of my random pendrive, you must see something like before.