# Measure USB read times for all devices using hdparm

Tags: usb, devices, hdparm

I would like to measure the read times of all mounted USB devices.

I [found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101791) that `hdparm` is suited for this:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdb1
```

However, I would like to attach several devices and iterate over `/dev/bus/usb/<bus>/<address>`. This gives me an error:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/bus/usb/003/002
read(2097152) returned 62 bytes
 BLKGETSIZE failed: Operation not permitted
BLKFLSBUF failed: Operation not permitted
```

(I found the bus and address via `lsusb`.)

How can I make this approach work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for i in $(cat /proc/partitions | grep -v "[0-9]$\|name" | awk '{ print $4 }'); do hdparm -tT /dev/"$i"; done
```

This loops through the `/proc/partitions` and retrieves the device names before passing those values to `hdparm`, which is meant to be run on devices, not partitions (e.g. /dev/sda not /dev/sda1).

As written the above command will also operate on the existing hard drives as well as USB devices.  To exclude them, modify the `grep -v` portion.  The above command will display all the lines which do not end in a `digit` or contain the word `name`.

For example, if you have two hard drives that you wish to exclude (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`), the above command could be changed to this:

```
for i in $(cat /proc/partitions | grep -v "[ab0-9]$\|name" | awk '{ print $4 }'); do hdparm -tT /dev/"$i"; done
```